# Refit existing Spark ML PipelineModel with new data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, spark-streaming, apache-spark-ml

I'm using Spark Structured Streaming - more or less - to taim my data with a DecisionTreeRegressor.

I'd like to reuse my already fitted PipelineModel to fit again on new data. 
Is it possible? 
I've already tried to load back my PipelineModel and add it's stages to a pipeline and fit the data on a new model.

```
      val modelDirectory =  "/mnt/D834B3AF34B38ECE/DEV/hadoop/model"
      var model : PipelineModel = _
      var newModel : PipelineModel = _
      var pipeline : Pipeline = _

        ..........

      val trainingData = //an instance of a dataframne
      val testData = //an instance of a dataframne

      val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
        .setInputCols(Array("routeId", "stopId", "month","dayOfWeek","hour","temperature","humidity","pressure","rain","snow","visibility"))
        .setOutputCol("features")

      val dt = new DecisionTreeRegressor()
        .setLabelCol("value")
        .setFeaturesCol("features")
        .setImpurity("variance")
        .setMaxDepth(30)
        .setMaxBins(32)
        .setMinInstancesPerNode(5)

      pipeline = new Pipeline()

      try {
        model = PipelineModel.load(modelDirectory)
        pipeline.setStages(model.stages)
      } catch {
        case iie: InvalidInputException => {
          pipeline.setStages(Array(assembler,dt))
          printf(iie.getMessage)
        }
        case unknownError: UnknownError => {
          printf(unknownError.getMessage)
        }
      }

      newModel = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

      // Make predictions.
      val predictions: DataFrame = model.transform(testData)

      // Select example rows to display.
      print(s"Predictions based on ${System.currentTimeMillis()} time train: ${System.lineSeparator()}")
      predictions.show(10, false)

      // Select (prediction, true label) and compute test error
      val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
        .setLabelCol("value")
        .setPredictionCol("prediction")
        .setMetricName("accuracy")
      val accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
```

You can find my full source code in: https://github.com/Hakuhun/bkk-data-process-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/hu/oe/bakonyi/bkk/BkkDataDeserializer.scala

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to refit an already fitted model in Spark 2.4.4.

For continuous learning machine learning solutions check the MLLibs documentation. You can achieve that with StreamingLinearRegressionWithSVG, StreamingKmeans, StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSVG.

Also, keep in mind that that is a streaming application, so may your pipeline is learning continuously